# TikZ: conditional nodes inside \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I want to use a `\foreach` construct to generate several pairs of nodes, except for one of them I want to do something different. This is what I tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]
    \foreach \x/\nm/\lbl in {0/na1/$\lnot a_1$, 1/na2/$\lnot a_2$, 2/na3/$\lnot a_3$, 3/dots/$\cdots$, 4/nan/$\lnot a_n$}
    \draw (\x,0) \if\nm{dots}\else node[dot](\nm){}\fi node[left=2pt]{\lbl};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This compiles just fine, but the "dots" node still has a dot next to it. How can I do this?

(Also, are there any better ways to have circle nodes which are named? using `circle(name)` didn't seem to work, so I'm just using `node[circle](name)`.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you do

```
\if\nm{dots}\else node[dot](\nm){}\fi
```

what happens is that TeX expands `\nm` and compares the two unexpandable tokens it finds; in the first cycle `\nm` is `na1`, so what happens is

```
\if na1{dots}\else node[dot](\nm){}\fi
```

and, since `n` and `a` are different, the "else" branch is followed. The same happens when `\nm` is `dots`: `d` and `o` are different.

What you need is a different test:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \def\test{dots}
  \foreach \x/\nm/\lbl in {0/na1/$\lnot a_1$, 1/na2/$\lnot a_2$, 2/na3/$\lnot a_3$, 3/dots/$\cdots$, 4/nan/$\lnot a_n$}
  \draw (\x,0) \ifx\nm\test\else node[dot](\nm){}\fi node[left=2pt]{\lbl};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

so TeX will compare the meaning of `\nm` with the meaning of `\test`

Another test that can work and doesn't require defining `\test` is

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\nm}{dots}=0 \else node[dot](\nm){}\fi
```

It has a limitation: you need pdflatex for it to work. If you plan using the code with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then say in the preamble

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\unistrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
```

and use `\unistrcmp` instead of `\pdfstrcmp`.

<sub>The reason is that XeTeX provides the command under the name `\strcmp` and LuaTeX doesn't provide it at all. The package defines `\pdf@strcmp` to be `\pdfstrcmp` if the engine is pdfTeX, `\strcmp` if the engine is XeTeX, and defines a Lua function in case the engine is LuaTeX. But the name has `@` in it, so we provide an `@`-free version.</sub>

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there any way to do this inline (without requiring `\test`)?

Answer (score 25):

You could use the `xifthen` package:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{ \node[circle,draw] (\x 1) at (0,\x) {\x};
    \node[circle,draw] (\x 2)at (2,\x) {\x};
    \ifthenelse{\NOT 4 = \x \AND \NOT 7 = \x}{\draw (\x 1) -- (\x 2);}{}
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The exaple means *if x is not four and also its not 7, then draw a line*, and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, we can rewrite the answer of Tom Bombadil as follows:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\IntStepInline{1}{1}{10}{
  \node[circle,draw] (#1 1) at (0,#1) {#1};
  \node[circle,draw] (#1 2) at (2,#1) {#1};
  \BoolVarOrTF{\IntCompare{4}={#1}}{\IntCompare{7}={#1}}{}{
    \draw (#1 1) -- (#1 2);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```