# How to draw tournament digraph with tkz-graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please, I want to draw a tournament digraph of order n (n=6 as example) with tikz.
But i don't know how i can exclude the repeated vertex in the seconde loop.
There is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

    \begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \SetGraphUnit{2}
            \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
            \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
            \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
            \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
            \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
            \AddVertexColor{blue}{5,1}
            \SetUpEdge[style={->,very thick},color=red]
            \foreach \v in {1,...,5}{
              \foreach \vv in {\v,...,6}{\Edge(\v)(\vv)};  
            };

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. As it is, it gives errors (undefined control sequence ...). Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: please add code in question.

Comment: I took liberty and instead you edit your question (complete code snippet and correct question title and text. You image is drawn with `tkz-graph` (which is based on `tikz`) . Next time this you should do yourself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\ifthenelse` construction.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{2}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
  \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
  \AddVertexColor{blue}{5,1}
  \SetUpEdge[style={->,very thick},color=red]
  \foreach \v in {1,...,5}
  {
    \foreach \vv in {\v,...,6}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\v=\vv}%
      {}% the empty `then` clause
      {%
        \Edge(\v)(\vv)% the `else` clause
      }  
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Per request

[image]

With french names for variables, as a token of appreciation to Alain's mysterious `tkz-graph` manual.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{2}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
  \Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
  \AddVertexColor{blue}{E,A}
  \SetUpEdge[style={->,very thick},color=red]
  \foreach \lettre/\nombre in {A/1,B/2,C/3,D/4,E/5}
  {
    \foreach \llettre/\nnombre in {A/1,B/2,C/3,D/4,E/5,F/6}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\nombre<\nnombre}
      {%
        \Edge(\lettre)(\llettre)
      }  
      {}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I looked it up [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph).

Comment: interesting solution (1). instead  `ifthenelse` you can use `{    \ifnum\v=\vv\else\Edge(\v)(\vv)\fi}`

Comment: @Zarko Thank you. Indeed looks more fundamental. I'm really not familiar with (also intimidated by) pure LaTeX (TeX ?) logic.

Comment: Really great ! simply thank's to you @marsupilam.

Comment: @HTeX, you are welcome, but here is habit (policy) that instead say "thank you" (what is fine, of course) rather up-vote answer and accept one, which the best fit your requirements :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
    \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{5,1}
    \SetUpEdge[style={-{Straight Barb[length=1mm,width=1.2mm]}, thick},color=red]
     \foreach \v [count=\vi from 2] in {1,...,5}{
     \foreach \vv in {\vi,...,6}{\Edge(\v)(\vv)};      
     }; 
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Addendum:**
Solution for your request in one of your comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
    \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
    \SetVertexNoLabel % <-- added
    \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \SetUpEdge[style={-{Straight Barb[length=1mm,width=1.2mm]}, thick},color=red]
     \foreach \v [count=\vi from 2] in {1,...,5}
     {
     \foreach \vv in {\vi,...,6}{\Edge(\v)(\vv)};
     };
     \SetVertexLabel
    \Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F} % <-- added
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{1,5}% <-- moved here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Addendum (2):**
solution for naming of vertices without their double drawing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
\renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
\renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\SetUpEdge[style={-{Straight Barb[length=1mm,width=1.2mm]}, thick},color=red]
 \foreach \v [remember=\v as \vi (initially A)] in {B,...,F}
 {
 \foreach \vv in {\v,...,F}{\Edge(\vi)(\vv)};
 };
\AddVertexColor{blue}{A,E}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marsupilam, ups, I forgot to move `\AddVertexColor{blue}{1,5}` on the place after `\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}`. Corected. Thank you very much for notice.

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment after your fix, even though it is worth explaining you place the vertices twice : First for joining, then again for labeling (because `tkz-graph` doesn' t seem to allow for labeling separately from node-naming).

Comment: @marsupilam, unfortunately I don't speak French, so the manual for tkz-graph is quite cryptic to me. I search in it for possibilities for labeling nodes independent to nodes' names but there is no example, which I could understand. To solve this problem in side drawing of edges drawing: temporary I didn't manage to make counter `\vi` as alphabetic.

Comment: too bad for the french, as the `tkz-graph` manual is entirely written in fully prosodic rhymed *alexandrin* verses. (More seriously, I think I remember there is some way to TeX-hackishly shift[by a constant-addititive-translation] a character code to another, possibly pushing A to 1 or the other way around... ?)

Comment: @marsupilam, meanwhile I prepare new solution which the problem of vertices naming is solved in loops for drawing edges. Now the counters in loops are alphabetic and double drawing of vertices is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, same output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \SetGraphUnit{2}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineColor}{white}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLightFillColor}{red}
  \renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{1pt}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
  \Vertices{circle}{1,2,3,4,5,6}
  \AddVertexColor{blue}{5,1}
  \SetUpEdge[style={->,very thick},color=red]
  \foreach \v in {1,...,5}
  {
    \foreach \vv in {\number\numexpr\v+1\relax,...,6}
    {
        \Edge(\v)(\vv)
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw this construction some days ago, and Zarko's answer made me think of it.

Comment: Thank's a lot for you Zarko and Marsupilam ! what about if i put an alphabetical vertices name set indeed of numerical. ie \Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}

Comment: @HTeX see my other answer for edited version.