# If condition with non integer numbers in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, conditionals, ifthenelse, spy

I have the following code to build the derivates of a given function:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\definecolor{vinho}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{vermelho}{rgb}{0.93, 0.11, 0.14}

\begin{document}

\def\a{2}
\foreach \b in {2.5,2.45,...,2.3,2.2,2.1,2.09,...,2.01}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=round,declare function = {
f(\x) = .5*(\x-1.5)*(\x-1.5)+1;},
spy using outlines={circle,magnification=2, height=0.5cm,size=1.5cm, connect spies}]
\clip (-1.8,-0.8) rectangle (5,3.5);
\draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[vinho,thick,domain=1:3.5,samples=200] plot(\x,{f(\x)}) node[right]{$f$};
\draw[vermelho,thick,domain=-1:1.91,samples=200] plot({\a + \x*(\b-\a)/(sqrt( (\b-\a)^2 + (f(\b)-f(\a))^2 ))},{f(\a) + \x*(f(\b)-f(\a))/(sqrt( (\b-\a)^2 + (f(\b)-f(\a))^2 ))}) node[right]{$s$};
\draw[densely dotted] (0,{f(\b)})  -- (\b,{f(\b)}) -- (\b,0) node[below]{$x_0+h$};
\draw[densely dotted] (0,{f(\a)}) -- (\a,{f(\a)}) -- (\a,0) node[below=0.08cm]{$x_0$};
\draw[fill] (\a,{f(\a)}) node[above=0.3cm]{$P$} circle (1pt);
\draw[fill] (\b,{f(\b)}) node[above]{$Q$} circle (1pt);
\draw[decoration={brace, raise=10pt},decorate,vinho!50] (0,{f(\a)}) -- node[left=10pt] {$f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$} (0,{f(\b)});
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate,vinho!50]  ({\a},-.250) -- node[below=6pt] {$h$} ({\b},-.250); 
\spy on ({2*\a},{2*f(\a)}) in node at (0.7,0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

For each \b in the looping, I build a different frame.

However, I would like to draw the spy:

```
\spy on ({2*\a},{2*f(\a)}) in node at (0.7,0.7);
```

only for b < 2.1. Tikz does not accept a condition when deals with non integer numbers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can the last solution of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187514/47927) maybe help you?

Comment: Cannot solve. I would like of another solution.

Comment: `\fpeval{trunc(\b/2.1)} < 1` maybe this condition is ok

Answer (score 9):

You could apply the last solution of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187514/47927) here:

The expression `int(ifthenelse(\b<2.1, 1, 0))` will output `1` or `0` (both integers) depending on whether `\b` is smaller than 2.1 or not.

This solution circumvents the problem that you cannot implement conditionals with non-integers in Ti*k*Z directly. It makes use of the `ifthenelse` function that comes with PGF to convert the non-integer to 0 or 1, which can then easily be tested with `\ifnum`.

(To decrease compilation time I reduced the sample size.)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\definecolor{vinho}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{vermelho}{rgb}{0.93, 0.11, 0.14}

\begin{document}

\def\a{2}
\foreach \b [evaluate=\b as \z using {int(ifthenelse(\b<2.1, 1, 0))}] in {2.2, 2.1, 2.09, 2.08} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, cap=round, declare function={
            f(\x) = .5*(\x - 1.5)*(\x - 1.5) + 1;
        }, spy using outlines={circle, magnification=2, height=0.5cm, size=1.5cm, connect spies}]

        \clip (-1.8,-0.8) rectangle (5,3.5);

        \draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$};

        \draw[vinho, thick, domain=1:3.5, samples=200] plot(\x, {f(\x)}) node[right] {$f$};
        \draw[vermelho, thick, domain=-1:1.91, samples=200] plot({\a + \x*(\b - \a)/(sqrt((\b - \a)^2 + (f(\b) - f(\a))^2))}, {f(\a) + \x*(f(\b) - f(\a))/(sqrt((\b - \a)^2 + (f(\b) - f(\a))^2))}) node[right] {$s$};
        
        \draw[densely dotted] (0,{f(\b)}) -- (\b,{f(\b)}) -- (\b,0) node[below] {$x_0 + h$};
        \draw[densely dotted] (0,{f(\a)}) -- (\a,{f(\a)}) -- (\a,0) node[below=0.08cm] {$x_0$};
        
        \draw[fill] (\a,{f(\a)}) node[above=0.3cm] {$P$} circle (1pt);
        \draw[fill] (\b,{f(\b)}) node[above] {$Q$} circle (1pt);
        
        \draw[decoration={brace, raise=10pt}, decorate, vinho!50] (0,{f(\a)}) -- node[left=10pt] {$f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)$} (0,{f(\b)});
        \draw[decoration={brace, mirror, raise=5pt}, decorate, vinho!50] ({\a},-0.250) -- node[below=6pt] {$h$} ({\b},-0.250); 
    
        \ifnum \z=1 
            \spy on ({2*\a},{2*f(\a)}) in node at (0.7,0.7);
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Output for `\b` = 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.09, 2.08, 2.07, 2.06, 2.05:
[image]